# Excel: Referencing an absolute cell after a column insert

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to reference a cell on an Excel Sheet, however when I insert a column I still wish to reference the original column (not the moved column).

Example:
in cell A1 I have a formula '=J1'
J1 has a value of 100, so A1 also equals 100.

If I insert a column to the left of J, I still wish to reference the new J1, but the formula in A1 changes to '=K1', even if I use '=$J1'

Is it possible to always reference J1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two more ways:-

```
=INDIRECT("J1")

=INDEX(1:1,10)
```

([Volatile](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/uvw/g/2013-09-14-excel-definition-volatile-functions.htm) functions are discouraged: INDEX may be preferred for this reason).

Answer (score 0):

Function `OFFSET` is probably what you need. Your example would be rewritten as

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,9)
```

More about this on Office Support ([here](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66), and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324991)).

Comment: thank you -- I have opted for INDEX in the next answer, to avoid the 'volatile' issue, as it is quite a large spreadhsset, but useful to know about OFFSET